# Equidistributed problem about polynomial with irrational coefficient

Tags: fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory

This problem is from Stein, Fourier Analysis,Chapter 4,problem 2(d).

Problem:Suppose that $P(x)=c_n x^n+……+c_0$ is a polynomial with real coefficients, where at least one of $c_1,……,c_n$ is irrational. Then the sequence $<P(n)>$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$.

The key point is to show that 
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty}\ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi i k P(n)} \ =0
$$
whenever $c_2,……,c_n$ is rational and $c_1$ irrational.

Since $<c_1n+c_0>$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$ if $c_1$ irrational. If the equation above holds, then by induction:

Assume that polynomial $P$ is of degree $m$ with at least one of $c_1,……,c_n$ irrational satisfies that $<P(n)>$ equidistributed in $[0,1)$, now consider the condition of degree $m+1$.We may discuss on two conditions.

(i)only $c_1$ is irrational, then by the equations above, we immediately get the solution;

(ii)otherwise consider $P(n+h)-P(n)$ for any positive integer $h$, a polynomial of degree $m$, along with at lease one irrational coefficient. By assumption, $<P(n+h)-P(n)>$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$,and hence $<P(n)>$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$.

My only drawback is to estimate the sum 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N e^{2 \pi i k P(n)}
$$
to conclude that 
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty}\ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi i k P(n)} \ =0
$$

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After a simple classification I have figured it out.

We could solve it by induction on the degree of the polynomial $P(x)$.

If $deg P(x)=1$, then $c_1 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and apparently $<c_1n+c_0>$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$.

Assume $deg P(x)=m$ and at least one of its coefficient $c_1,……,c_m$ is irrational, then $<P(n)>$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$.

Now consider the situation of $deg P(x)=m+1$, we may divide it into two parts:

(i)If $c_{m+1} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, then for any $h \in \Bbb{Z_+}$ we have $$P(n+h)-P(n)=\sum_{j=0}^m \bar{c_j}x^j$$  a polynomial of degree $m$, along with $\bar{c_m}$ irrational. Then by the assumption above: $<P(n+h)-P(n)>$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$, therefore by Weyl's theorem: $<P(n)>$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$.

(ii)If $c_{m+1}=\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$, then for $N$ big eough, there exists the unique $l,r$ such that $N=lq+r(0 \le r \le q-1)$. Set $P(x)=\frac{p}{q}x^{m+1} + Q(x)$, where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$ with at least one of $c_1,……,c_m$ irrational.

Notice that
$$
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N e^{2 \pi ik \frac{p}{q} \left( x^{m+1}+Q(n) \right)}
=\frac{1}{N} \left[ \sum_{j=0}^l e^{2 \pi ik Q(jq)} + …… +e^{2\pi ik \frac{r^m p}{q}} \sum_{j=0}^le^{2 \pi ikQ(jq+r)}
+e^{2\pi ik \frac{(r+1)^mp}{q}} \sum_{j=0}^{l-1}e^{2 \pi ik Q(jq+r+1)}+
……+ e^{2 \pi ik \frac{(q-1)^m p}{q}}\sum_{j=0}^{l-1} e^{2 \pi ik Q(j+q-1)} \right]
$$

Since $0 < \frac{l}{M} < \frac{l+1}{N} < \frac{2}{q}$, then 
$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N e^{2 \pi ik \left( \frac{p}{q}x^{m+1}+Q(n) \right)} \to 0(N \to \infty)$$

Consequently $<P(n)>$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$.