# Proof $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}N^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^N e^{-ik^2x}=0$ for all $x\notin 2\pi\mathbb Q$

Tags: calculus

The formula has no analytic expression. Is there good way to prove that.

Comment: @Winther why do you refer to Gauss sums?  Here $x/2\pi$ is not rational, so the terms in the sum are not roots of unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's rewrite your sum so it looks more conventional: setting $x = -2\pi\alpha$, your average is $(1/N)\sum_{k=1}^N e^{2\pi i(\alpha k^2)}$.

That this sum tends to $0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$ is a special case of an equidistribution theorem of Weyl, who showed for any polynomial $p(t)$ with at least one irrational coefficient that the sequence $p(k) \bmod 1$ is equidistributed. Take the polynomial to be $p(t) = \alpha t^2$.  A consequence of the Weyl equidistribution theorem is that $(1/N)\sum_{k=1}^N e^{2\pi i m(\alpha k^2)} \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$ for every nonzero integer $m$.  Your average is the case $m = 1$.

This problem has been discussed already at [Equidistributed problem about polynomial with irrational coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815972/equidistributed-problem-about-polynomial-with-irrational-coefficient).

Comment: Yes, but I didn't get the result of stein's problem 2(a). I wander if there a simpler proof for that.

Comment: Weyl's theorem about polynomials with at least one irrational coefficient is treated in many texts that discuss equidistribution, so if you do not like Stein's treatment then just look elsewhere. You know now that your original question is addressed by a well-known theorem about equidistributed sequences, so now the rest is up to you.